# Make TextView shown as Menu item

Tags: android, xml, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I created an `autoCompleteTextView` that shows some offers.

Since I couldn't find a way to make the first item of the `autocompleteTextView` fixed and not scrollable, I placed a `TextView` in between the `autoCompleteTextView` and its popup.

[image]

as you can see the TextView doesn't have the same view as the pop-menu, it is less "3d" I had say, or without shadow but it just doesn't look the same.

Is there any attribute to make it look like part of the menu items?

My xml is:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/ATV_Title"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset = "60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_underline_gray"
        android:dropDownHeight="150dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:hint="@string/ActivitySearch_Auto"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Ib_Clear"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ATV_Title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ATV_Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_addManually"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold"
        android:hint="Cant find your result? Add manually"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:paddingStart="18dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ATV_Title"/>
```

I also tried using a custom adapter that looks as follows to do the job but without success:

```
public class AutoCompleteImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<String> fullList;
private ArrayList<String> mOriginalValues;
private ArrayFilter mFilter;
private Boolean noResults;
private TextView tv_name;
private ImageView im_cover;
private List<String> url, id;

private StorageReference storageRef;
private FirebaseFirestore db;

public AutoCompleteImageAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects, List<String> url, List<String> id, Boolean noResult) {

    super( context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects );
    fullList = (ArrayList<String>) objects;
    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>( fullList );
    noResults = noResult;
    this.url = url;
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (fullList.size() > 40) {
        return 40;
    } else {
        return fullList.size();
    }
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return fullList.get( position );
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    View row = convertView;

    String id = this.id.get( position );
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( getContext() );

    if (row == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate( R.layout.item_auto_add, parent, false );
    }

    tv_name = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.item_drop );
    tv_name.setText( fullList.get( position ) );

    im_cover = row.findViewById( R.id.iv_itemCover );
    String Url = url.get( position );
    if (id.length() > AppConstants.UPLOADED_item_LENGTH) {
        storageRef.child( "/itemCovers/" + Url + "/" + Url + ".jpg" ).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.with( parent.getContext() ).load( uri ).resize( 110, 160 ).into( im_cover );
            }
        } ).addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.d( "ERROR", exception + "" );
            }
        } );
    } else {
        Picasso.with( parent.getContext() ).load( Uri.parse( Url ) ).error( R.drawable.ic_nocover ).resize( 110, 160 ).into( im_cover );
    }


    return row;

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
    }
    return mFilter;
}

private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
    private Object lock;

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (mOriginalValues == null) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>( fullList );
            }
        }

        if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>( mOriginalValues );
                results.values = list;
                results.count = list.size();
            }
        } else {
            final String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

            ArrayList<String> values = mOriginalValues;
            int count = values.size();

            ArrayList<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>( count );

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String item = values.get( i );
                if (item.toLowerCase().contains( prefixString )) {
                    newValues.add( item );
                }

            }

            results.values = newValues;
            results.count = newValues.size();
        }

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        if (results.values != null) {
            fullList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        } else {
            fullList = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        if (results.count > 0) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}

public void clear() {
    if (fullList != null) {
        fullList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add "tv_addManually" to the item set of the adapter? and give it a different click handler.

You could, for example, check if the first item is clicked, then you let the user add manually.

Comment: Because if it will be part of the adapter it will scroll like any other item. Since I couldnt find a way to make it static as a header, I decided to try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own AutoCompleteTextView extending EditText and show/hide ListPopupWindow with header view via setPromptView, setPromptPosition methods

```
val popup = ListPopupWindow(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
popup.adapter = MyAdapter()


popup.setPromptView(fixedView)
popup.setPromptPosition(ListPopupWindow.POSITION_PROMPT_ABOVE)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement custom adapter (updated my question) but without success since it became diffecult to me with all the filter stuff so thought to go on the easy option as I asked above.

Comment: I said you to implement Custom AutoCompleteTextView not Adapter

Comment: ok so do you mind giving a fuller answer to demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: Open AutoCompleteTextView class of Android library. There you can see private popupWindow property. You should code the same but modify the ListPopUpWindow initialization with the code I've posted above. Another solution is to change the properties of private field mPopup via reflection